# Embedding function in Keras not working for float 16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

While running the imdb_lstm.py from keras examples 
(code can be found here)
https://gist.github.com/raghavgurbaxani/20c08c55eca5e97cd5c51389c091fc9f

I get the error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:   indices[14,25] = 20000 is not in [0, 20000)
[[Node: embedding_1/GatherV2 = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_HALF,
_class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/embedding_1/GatherV2_grad/Reshape"],
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read, embedding_1/Cast, lstm_1/TensorArrayUnstack/range/start)]]

Caused by op u`embedding_1/GatherV2`, defined at:
```

Does tf.gather not support float 16 ?

(Using tensorflow 1.8.0, keras 2.2.0 on the Titan X)

Thanks :)

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in your post instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are trying to get the index 20000, but that index doesn't exist. Your indices are from 0 to 19999.